# Database connection not working while logging in to Symfony 3.4 app

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a Symfony website on Azure MySQL + PHP web app, and it deployed, but I was facing this error:

```
The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar; you need to quote the scalar
```

So I wrapped up the db user and password in quotation but now when I am trying to login to my website I am facing this error:

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

It seems the db connection is not working and whenever the code runs the query it breaks. I tried to run simple mysqli query as well and fetched the result successfully.

My Symfony version is 3.4.

PHP version is 7.2

MySQL version is 5.1

***CODE:***

***Parameters.yml***

```
    parameters:
        database_host: '`db_host`'
        database_port: null
        database_name: db_name
        database_user: '`db_user`'
        database_password: '`my_db_password`'
        mailer_transport: smtp
        mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
        mailer_user: null
        mailer_password: null
        secret: b379ec1bf07cf3925582e96b26ffe5ad0052aff8
```

***Config.yml***

```
    doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: 5.1
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

Comment: Can you post your actual connection code please?

Comment: @War10ck added, please check the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding URL based database configuration in my config.yml file as below.

```
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            server_version: 5.1
            driver: mysqli
            host: '%database_host%'
            port: '%database_port%'
            dbname: '%database_name%'
            user: '%database_user%'
            password: '%database_password%'
            # if the url option is specified, it will override the above config
            url: pdo-mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
```

References: [Link 1](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) [Link 2](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

According to your error information `The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar; you need to quote the scalar`, it was caused by the character `@` which is a reserved indicator in YAML 1.2. Please refer to [the YAML offical specification document](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) to know it via search `@` in browser. And more note details for using Symfony YAML (3.4) to parse YAML file, please see [The YAML Format](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/yaml/yaml_format.html) on the Symfony offical site, and here is a short reference below.

> Strings containing any of the following characters must be quoted.
>   Although you can use double quotes, for these characters it is more
>   convenient to use single quotes, which avoids having to escape any
>   backslash :
>
> :, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, #, ?, |, -, <, >, =, !, %, **@**, `
>
> The double-quoted style provides a way to express arbitrary strings, by
>   using \ to escape characters and sequences. For instance, it is very
>   useful when you need to embed a \n or a Unicode character in a string.

Within your description, I can't see any `@` in your code, therefore that I can not supply any code to help fixing the error. But I reproduce the error information via a simple code and hope it helps.

```
<?php
include_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
$value = Yaml::parse("hello: @world");
printf($value);
?>
```

The first character `@` of `hello` cause the same error. Maybe, the same issue happened when you refer the variable in `Config.yml`. If you can update your code for more missing details, it's useful to help fixing.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer :)